# java newbie questions regarding arrays

Tags: java, arrays, object

Can anyone please help me with these 2 questions please ? I've read the official documentation and want to make sure

1. What happens when an array of objects is created?

   a.  the array contains objects of the specified type of initialized to null or 0

   b.  the array contains references to objects of the specified type created earlier in the program

   c.  the array contains objects of the specified type created earlier in the program

   d.  the array contains locations for references to objects of the specified type

I choose B option

2. what is combined with an array identifier to provide a reference to a single element of the array?

   a.  variable

   b.  primitive value

   c.  array value

   d.  index value

I choose D option as the identifier is for ex "int[]"  and in the brackets you put the index

Thank you in advance

Comment: why do you choose B for the first question (hint: it's not B [technically, none of the answers is (completely) correct)

Comment: A really, but everything is null. that word initialized shouldn't be there. after creation you fill them with primitives or references to objects. and on question 2 is D the answer. But technically it would be memory start array + (item size byte count * index) to get hte memory address of the reference.

Comment: @Tschallacka not with 'primitives or references to objects'.

Comment: well if you have an array with objects, you have an array filled with memory primitive type addresses where the objects reside. And primitive arrays can be filled with primitives because they have a fixed byte size. Above the hood of course you don't see it.

Comment: @Tschallacka the question is about an array of Objects. It's filled with their default value,being 'null', never 0.

Comment: True, but those answers are confusing as hell because they also imply primitive arrays the way they are worded. But if it's a primitive array like int or char or boolean it would initialize with 0. And techinally null is also 0 way deep under the hood because zero is also a valid null pointer constant.(it references address 0, which is the address accepted as nothing in most applications. Hence the term null pointer)

Comment: @Stultuske I watched a video that said an array has references to that object :(

Comment: @lupul666 once there are actually references put in there, sure, but that doesn't happen on a basic array creation. What video did you watch?

Comment: @Stultuske https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0DaCf_5c_QQ   :(

Comment: as in the video, there's only an actual reference in there, if you've assigned it, but don't look at video's like this to learn Java, you're better of by buying a good textbook. In the video, he at one point states that cars[10] would get the 10th element, right after explaining how array indices are 0 based. This type of video's can only confuse you further

Answer (score 3):

For question 1, the answer is (should be)

> a. the array contains objects of the specified type of initialized to
>   null or 0

I say should be, because there is an error here. Since we are talking about an array of `Objects` (and not primitive types), the default value will always be `null`, never 0 (this would be the case for an `array` of `int`).

You expected it to contain previously created instances? So, in the next snippet, what would, according to you, be the content of the array?

```
String one = "one";
String two = "two";
String three = "three";

String[] myArr = new String[2];
```

The JVM has no idea of knowing what you want to be in there, and, if you would want the previously existing instances, which ones you wanted, since there is 1 more than there's room in the array.

Therefor, unless specifically set to a value, after creation of an array, the elements contain the `default value` for that type, for `Objects`, that being `null`.

Your assumption for the second question is correct.
It's indeed the index that refers to the instance stored in a specific location of the array.

So:

```
String[] arr = {"First element", "Second element"};
String element = arr[0]; // arrays are 0-based
System.out.println(element); // will print "First element"
```

Here, however, there is some ambiguity as well:

```
b. primitive value
```

Could also be considered correct (depends on the explanation) since the index is always a primitive value. But I would stick with answer D. They might mean something entirely different with primitive value (which I assume they do) but this can't be fully ascertained from the question.